# How do I detect if a value has been added to array slot? (java)

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer and i've gotten stuck.

I've set up an array here which has worked how I want it to.
Although now I need a way to check the very last slot (data[5]) to see if any value has been placed within it since there is no guarantee in my code that each array slot will be assigned a value.

Below is my working array setup:

```
public final int[] data;

//Constructor
public MyArrayList() {
    this.data = new int[6];

}
```

And here is what I've tried:

```
if(data[5] == null){
        data[5] = value;
        truth = true;

    } else {

        truth = false;
    }
```

Note that this code is trying to detect if anything is in there, and place another value in if it can see there hasn't been any code written there.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

`int` is a primitive type in Java, so it will never be `null`. If you want to keep track of how much of the array you've "used", you can add a second field to the class to keep up with it.

```
public class MyArrayList {

  private final int[] data;
  private int index;

  public MyArrayList() {
    data = new int[6];
    index = 0;
  }

  ...

}
```

Then whenever you "push" something new to the list, you put it at the `index` position and increment `index`. If `index` is ever equal to the length of the list, then you've exhausted the space you allocated.

Comment: why not box data to Integer?

Comment: @DCR Because this is likely an exercise for a student of Java to learn the details of manipulating arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Integer class instead of the primitive type. It allows to assign a value  or a null value. With this you can apply the logic that you described.

```
data = new Integer[6];

if (data[5] == null)
    data[5] = value;
```